# Append Output results

Tags: shell, unix, tee

I'm running a validation software and I want all of the output sent to a text file and have the results of multiple files placed/appended to the same file. I thought my code was working, but I just discovered I'm only getting the results from 1 file output to the text file.

```
java -jar /Applications/epubcheck-3.0.1/epubcheck-3.0.1.jar ~/Desktop/Validator/*.epub 2>&1 | tee -a ~/Desktop/Validator/EPUBCHECK3_results.txt

open ~/Desktop/Validator/EPUBCHECK3_results.txt
```

**EDIT**

When I run the same .jar file using Windows command line it will process a batch of files and appeand the results appropriately. I would just do this, but it would mean having to switch work stations and transferring files to validate them. I would like to get this running through the Unix shell on my Mac system so that I don't have to do unnecessary work. Command line that IS working below:

```
FOR /f %%1 in ('dir /b "C:\Users\scrawfo\Desktop\epubcheck\drop epubs here\*.epub"') do (
echo %%1 >> epubcheck.txt
java -jar "C:\Users\scrawfo\Desktop\epubcheck\epubcheck-3.0.jar" "C:\Users\scrawfo\Desktop\epubcheck\drop epubs here\%%1" 2>> epubcheck.txt
echo. >> epubcheck.txt)
notepad epubcheck.txt
del epubcheck.txt
```

Comment: Never seen `open` used in a shellscript before.  Are you just trying to print the contents of the file?  If so, just use `cat`.

Comment: I'm literally calling to open the text file after it's done running the .jar validation.

Comment: What you are doing should work.  Perhaps the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I just edited my question. The same JAR works perfectly on Windows using command line. I'm only having trouble when trying through Unix

Answer (score 0):

syntax provided by you is correct there might be some problem with java output or something Try Executing it without redirection

```
cat test
```

**Output:-**

> ## This is Test File ...............

Next Executed Command with same syntax

```
ps l 2>&1 | tee -a test
```

**Output:-**

> F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME
>   COMMAND 4     0  3287     1  20   0   4060   572 n_tty_ Ss+  tty2
>   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2 4     0  3289     1  20   0   4060   572
>   n_tty_ Ss+  tty3       0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty3 4     0  3291
>   1  20   0   4060   576 n_tty_ Ss+  tty4       0:00 /sbin/mingetty
>   /dev/tty4 4     0  3295     1  20   0   4060   576 n_tty_ Ss+  tty5
>   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty5 4     0  3297     1  20   0   4060   572
>   n_tty_ Ss+  tty6       0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty6 4     0 19086
>   1  20   0   4060   572 n_tty_ Ss+  tty1       0:00 /sbin/mingetty
>   /dev/tty1 4     0 20837 20833  20   0 108432  2148 wait   Ss   pts/0
>   0:00 -bash 4     0 21471 20837  20   0 108124  1036 -      R+   pts/0 
>   0:00 ps l 0     0 21472 20837  20   0 100908   664 pipe_w S+   pts/0
>   0:00 tee -a test

**Checked File**

```
cat test
```

**Output:-(Appended properly)**

> ## This is Test File ...............
>
> F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND 4     0 
>   3287     1  20   0   4060   572 n_tty_ Ss+  tty2       0:00
>   /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2 4     0  3289     1  20   0   4060   572
>   n_tty_ Ss+  tty3       0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty3 4     0  3291
>   1  20   0   4060   576 n_tty_ Ss+  tty4       0:00 /sbin/mingetty
>   /dev/tty4 4     0  3295     1  20   0   4060   576 n_tty_ Ss+  tty5
>   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty5 4     0  3297     1  20   0   4060   572
>   n_tty_ Ss+  tty6       0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty6 4     0 19086
>   1  20   0   4060   572 n_tty_ Ss+  tty1       0:00 /sbin/mingetty
>   /dev/tty1 4     0 20837 20833  20   0 108432  2148 wait   Ss   pts/0
>   0:00 -bash 4     0 21471 20837  20   0 108124  1036 -      R+   pts/0 
>   0:00 ps l 0     0 21472 20837  20   0 100908   664 pipe_w S+   pts/0
>   0:00 tee -a test

Comment: I ran the command without redirecting the output to another file and it is still only evaluating one of the files in the directory. What I need to to do is evaluate all *.epub files in the directory and give me the output for all of them

Comment: Can You share the output

Comment: Epubcheck Version 3.0.1

Validating against EPUB version 2.0
ERROR: /Users/scrawfo/Desktop/Validator/?????????????.epub/OEBPS/toc.ncx(21,45): assertion failed: different playOrder values for navPoint/navTarget/pageTarget that refer to same target
ERROR: /Users/scrawfo/Desktop/Validator/?????????????.epub/OEBPS/toc.ncx(27,45): assertion failed: different playOrder values for navPoint/navTarget/pageTarget that refer to same target

Check finished with warnings or errors